# Can all images be reloaded at once with the node wrangler?

Tags: materials, node-editor

I have multiple textures that are used across many objects. Some of them are being revised along the process by previewing them in preview render. I want to know when using the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> does it update all of the textures at once or is it per material?